# is it possible to decrypt a file which is encrypted using "IonCube" encryption?

Tags: encryption

There is a file in my server which is encrypted using IonCube encryption, is it possible to decrypt this file? if so what are the steps to be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what i could find out about ionCube in the last five minutes, it compiles the code to some bytecode and encrypts that bytecode. decryption can be done on a licensed machine only.

so i think it will be possible (with more or less efford) to tamper the runtime on a licensed machine to obtain the unencoded bytecode, since all needed crypto stuff has to be there for the normal operation.

decompiling that bytecode back to readable PHP code is a totally different thing ... at least all comments will be gone, and since it does compiler optimizations, it's unlikely to be able to reproduce the same code. probably a great efford.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible, i lost the plain text source code to some of my projects and only had encrypted copies left, there is a certain web service out there that will decrypt ionCube php files, complete with original spacing and comments... Although it isn't cheap!